# How to implement DirectShow Library to build a WPF Application

Tags: wpf, directshow, screen-capture

How to implement DirectShow Library to build a WPF Application that can make
1. capture the video from webcam 
2. screen capture to a video file

I try to find example code for the absolutely beginner

Answer (score 1):

This codeplex project ([Touchless](http://touchless.codeplex.com/)) should give you a head start.  It is pretty easy to look at the code and see how it works.

Comment: Can Touchless can video make video file recorded from webcam? Or make screen capture video file?

Comment: not out of the box, but it can get you access to the video stream and has some of the DirectShow interfaces mapped into .NET.